# Handling shared objects in a JPQL select

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Parent entity that has a OneToMany relationship with child entity. The ManyToOne on the child is optional.

When performing a query on the Child I can perform a LEFT JOIN FETCH on the parent to get all the parents in one query. Unfortunately, the parent entity could be duplicated many times in the returned child set adding a lot of overhead marshaling the results.

Is there a way to do this query (a) without having to do an individual select on every parent when I call "child.getParent()" (i.e. no LEFT JOIN FETCH) and (b) without retrieving a duplicate set of data for each parent if I do a LEFT JOIN FETCH?

Logically what I'd like to do is this:

1. Perform child query (this may return 100 children entities)
2. Collect the parent objects (this may only return 50 parent entities)
3. Set each child to reference its retrieved parent.

If this isn't clear and you need some code I can provide it. But it is a pretty basic example:

```
@Entity
public class Child ... {
    ...
    @ManyToOne( optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn( name = "parent_id" )
    private Parent parent;
    ...
}
```

This query will require a do an individual select on parent each time I do I call "child.getParent()":

```
SELECT c FROM Child c WHERE c.id IN :childIds;
```

This query will load duplicate data for each parent that is not unique in the result set:

```
SELECT c FROM Child c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.parent WHERE c.id IN :childIds;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you measured the difference between the query which loads the 100 children, and the query which loads them with their parent? Have you proven it caused a significant performance problem? If not, you're doing premature optimization. Just use a left join fetch. Anyway, I really doubt doing 2 queries would take less time than doing just one.

Comment: Yeah, the query that loads each parent individually is MUCH slower so much so that it impacts the user. The LEFT JOIN FETCH is a lot faster but I'm still looking for some extra performance gains. The parent entity has a few long string fields and the extra unnecessary marshaling of these is a hot spot. The data marshaling is more expensive than the actual query executions.